# Firebase Auth Sign In Apple revokeToken error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am implementing the Apple Login function using Firebase.

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?hl=ko#configure_sign_in_with_apple)

The membership registration has been completed and displayed properly on the console.
The problem is the deletion of members.

```
Task {
   do {
     try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
     try await user?.delete()
     self.updateUI()
   } catch {
     self.displayError(error)
   }
}
```

There was an error using this code.

```
Task {
   do {
      try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
      print("Good")
   } catch {
      print("Error")
   }

   do {
      try await user?.delete()
      print("Good Delete")
   } catch {
      print("Error")
   }
}
```

I modified 'auth.auth().revokeToken' and 'user?'delete()' to run in two steps as above code.

The error occurred in 'auth.auth().revokeToken'. However, Delete was successful and the test account was deleted from the Firebase console.

1. May I know why 'auth.auth().revokeToken' doesn't work?
2. Is there no problem if I don't do 'auth.auth().revokeToken'?
3. How can I print an 'revokeToken' error?

Below is my code.

```
private func deleteCurrentUser() {
    do {
        let nonce = try self.randomNonceString()
        self.currentNonce = nonce
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.nonce = self.sha256(nonce)

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    } catch {
        // In the unlikely case that nonce generation fails, show error view.
        print("실패")
    }
}

private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
    let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
    let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
    let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        return String(format: "%02x", $0)
    }.joined()
    
    return hashString
}


private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
    precondition(length > 0)
    let charset: Array<Character> =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
    var result = ""
    var remainingLength = length
    
    while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
            var random: UInt8 = 0
            let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
            if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
            }
            return random
        }
        
        randoms.forEach { random in
            if remainingLength == 0 {
                return
            }
            
            if random < charset.count {
                result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                remainingLength -= 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result
}


func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,
                            didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    guard let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential else {
        print("Unable to retrieve AppleIDCredential")
        return
    }

    guard let _ = self.currentNonce else {
        fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
    }

    guard let appleAuthCode = appleIDCredential.authorizationCode else {
        print("Unable to fetch authorization code")
        return
    }

    guard let authCodeString = String(data: appleAuthCode, encoding: .utf8) else {
        print("Unable to serialize auth code string from data: \(appleAuthCode.debugDescription)")
        return
    }

    let user = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser

    Task {

        do {
        try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
            print("Good")
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }



        do {
        try await user?.delete()
            print("Good Delete")
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not much different from what Google told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reconfigure to something like this

```
let task = Task {
   do {
      try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
      print("Good")
      try await user?.delete()
      print("Good Delete")
   } catch {
      print("Error \(error)")
   }
}
```

Putting your delete code below the `catch` is basically saying delete no matter what.

By putting it in the `do` below the `try` the code to delete will be skipped if the call fails.

Also, notice that I added `error` to the `print`, that will print the actual error instead of just a generic message.

Also, make sure you hold on to the task at `class` or `struct` level, that way you can tell when the operations is actually done.

Comment: I modified the code as you told me.

The errors are as follows.
'Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomainCode=credit4 "Code flow is not available for Apple" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription= code flow is not available for Apple. FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_CREDINTIAL}'

Thanks to you, I checked the error.

Comment: The cause was found through this error. The problem was that you didn't enter a selection.

I thought it was working properly without inputting the options.